# Preventing images loading in gallery

Tags: android

In my app I'm encrypting the image and saving it in a specific folder in SDcard, When I open the gallery of the device it's showing the folder and the encrypted image,  I don't want my images in gallery. How can I do this? Heard that .nomedia is a solution, But I want something programmatically.

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-prevent-a-directory-from-being-scanned-by-android-gallery/

Also referrd this link but I am not find it effective.

Comment: If you are encrypting the image and changing the file extension, android should not be able to read it.

Comment: am not changing the file extension.saving as .jpg, But the folder is visible in gallery

Answer (score 0):

The directory you are saving the images, make it nomedia.

If the folder has a dot before the name, it will be automatically excluded from the Gallery. Gallery completely overlooks these folders, so it saves you time upon Gallery launch. Essentially, prefixing with the dot turns the folder into a hidden folder, so many applications will be unable to see the folder after the change — this includes some file managers. If you’re sure it’s okay to make the folder hidden, go ahead. If not, there’s another method we’ll go through shortly that you might prefer to use.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/hide-private-picture-folders-gallery-android/